# What are the best practices for constant types in typescript?

Tags: typescript, typescript-typings

```
enum ENUM_POSITION_TYPE {
  LEFT = 1,
  RIGHT = 2
}

// type PositionType = 1 | 2
type PositionType = ???

export let a1: PositionType = ENUM_POSITION_TYPE.RIGHT //correct
export let a2: PositionType = 1 as const //correct
export let a3: PositionType = 3 //typescript error
```

I don't want to write code like this `type PositionType = 1 | 2`, When I add an enum, I don’t want to change the type

Comment: Have you tried `type PositionType = ENUM_POSITION_TYPE`?

Comment: Or just mark the type of a1  as `ENUM_POSITION_TYPE` directly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

TypeScript doesn't track the specific literal types for Enum values. This becomes more apparent when you see that the following also doesn't have a type error:

```
let x: typeof ENUM_POSITION_TYPE["LEFT"] = 3;
```

I recommend the following approach instead

```
const ENUM_POSITION_TYPE = {
  LEFT: 1,
  RIGHT: 2
} as const;

type PositionType = typeof ENUM_POSITION_TYPE[keyof typeof ENUM_POSITION_TYPE];
```